# Is system file cache shared by all the processes in the system?

Tags: kernel

Is system file cache shared by all the processes in the system or private to each process? (How about on Windows and Linux?)

As to *system file cache* here, I'm not meaning the application layer IO cache implemented by various IO libraries but the cache implemented by OS kernel which can be flush using sync on Linux and FlushFileBuffers on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file cache is available for any user/kernel process, you might want to read this:

http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/inside-cache-manager

Answer (score 0):

On Linux it is shared. Not sure how Windows kernel deals with that.